# Broken image is shown when fetched from mysql database in django

Tags: python, django

Iam trying to fetch image from my database but the image is broken I don't know correctly what I missed Please give me a solution.

VIEWS.PY

```
def display_images(request):
    allimages = GetImage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'show.html', {'images': allimages})
```

MODELS.PY

```
class GetImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/")
class Meta:
    db_table = "gallery"
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
path('show', views.display_images),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

SETTINGS.PY

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

SHOW.HTML

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Django Display Images</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for img in images %}
<tr>
<td>{{img.title}}</td>
<td><img src="/{{ BASIC_DIR }}/{{img.img}}" width="120"/> 
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please give one solution regarding about this fetching images.